# Can I configure a profile to deactivate after 90 days without access to Salesforce Service Cloud?

Tags: change-set

At the company where I work, we have several profiles that use Salesforce Service Cloud, but many of these profiles have not been used for a long time. And from time to time I have to check each access profile and their last login to delete those who are not using the platform. I know that in Salesfoce Marleting Cloud there is a setting that deactivates users who have not logged in for 90 days, I would like to know if there is something similar in the Service Cloud, from what I researched there is not...but maybe I missed something or you can suggest me another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Profiles are metadata and there's no "deactivate after no use within last n days" feature

It sounds like you want to deactivate users who have not used Service Cloud in 90 days.

To do that, you need to query `SELECT Id, LastLoginDate FROM User WHERE ...` and then update those User's `IsActive` to `false`

This could be done in a Schedule-Triggered Flow or a Schedulable Apex job.

Programmatically deactivating Profiles is more complex as you have to

- Remove all users from the Profile
- Use the Metadata API to delete the Profile